# Block submit if value greater than one php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, submit

I want to disable the submit if the sum of all select values is  bigger than one. And pass if the value < 1.

```
    <?php 
$options = array( "0.00","0.05","0.10","0.15","0.20","0.25","0.30","0.35","0.40","0.45","0.50","0.55","0.60","0.65","0.70","0.75","0.80","0.85","0.90","0.95","1" ); // ◄■■ OPTIONS ARE STATIC (ALWAYS THE SAME).
while ( $row_menuid = mysqli_fetch_array( $dat_menuid ) ) // ◄■ DISPLAY 
    <SELECT>
    s.
{ echo "
<select name='corp_resp&{$row_menuid['menuId']}&{$_SESSION['UtilizadorID']}&{$dateTime}&{$toEchosave}'>\n"; // ◄■■ CORP_RESP&1,CORP_RESP&2.
 foreach ( $options as $opt ) // ◄■■ DISPLAY OPTIONS.
     echo "<option value='$opt'>$opt</option>\n";
 echo "</select>
\n"; // ◄■■ SELECT END.
}
?>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<script>
    $('select').change(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $('select :selected').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        }
                                  );
        $("#sum").html(sum);
        if (sum > 1) {
            alert('Block!')
        }
        else {
            alert('Give the value !')
        }
    }
                      );
</script>
<?php
if ($idfilho == 1) 
{
    echo "<td align=\"center\"  bgcolor='FFFFFF'>   <a href='avaliacoes2.php?menuId=".$id."'>Seleccionar</a> </td>";
}
else
{
    echo "";
}
echo    '</tr>';
}
}
echo"</table>";
echo "<div id='sum'>SUM OF SELECTED OPTIONS</div>";
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo ('<input type="submit"  value="Submeter" class="link-style2"  />'); ?>
```

The variable to get the value in each select option value is working but i want to get only in the final sum and compare. If sum > 1 then block the submit if not then you can submit the value. I was trying with alerts but is not the correct way to do.

Thank you.

Comment: "Block the submit" in the sense of disabling the submit button (leaving the user to wonder how to re-enable it), or "block the submit" as in let the user press the submit button but then show a message and stop the submit at that point?

Comment: @nnnnnn The point is not be possible when you click the button submit if the value is bigger then one. And give a message you can´t submit because the value is bigger than one.

Comment: Do bear in mind that any client-side (javascript) solution you implement for restricting form submissions is easily circumvented and should not be relied upon for insuring valid input is submitted.  It's up to the server-side (PHP) to confirm that any submitted user data is valid before doing any further processing, the client-side validation should be considered no more than a usability aid

Comment: @GordonM, how to do that? I need to do that? Make the condition on the submit php, how to get the value of sum and convert to php variable for do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var sum = 0;

    $('select').change(function(){
        $('select :selected').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });

        $("#sum").html(sum);
    }

    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        if(sum > 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here, you need to make the variable `sum` global and add an event handler `submit` of `form` element. In the event handler, you can check the condition if the `sum` is greater than `1` or not. If it is greater than `1`, you can prevent the form from being submitted by `e.preventDefault()` which stops the event from running.

You can also provide alert box or do something when it is exceeds `1` like this one:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if(sum > 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Blocked!");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem is the submit is outside of JavaScript.   echo ('<input type="submit"  value="Submeter" class="link-style2"  />');

Comment: I don't get you. Can you be specific?

Comment: I try the code you tell me but is not working. I submit the same and don´t show the sum increase with values put on select options.

Comment: Do you actually have `form` added in your code? I don't see any `form` tags in your code.

Comment: <form id="teste" method="post" action="teste.php">   is that i use. Redirect to another page for do statistics.

Comment: I think your code always submits the form since you are only able to select one option at a time. Right?

Comment: In that moment we have 3 select option values, i do that in database. Can 1 option value can be 5 option value. The sum is working because i put the values in the select options and in print you see add the values one by one. The idea is get the total sum and do restriction in php. Can i do that? Because i check in your posts that is not able to do.

Comment: Best Example convert JavaScript value to PHP:

JavaScript

<script type="text/javascript">
    var sum = 12;
</script>
PHP

<?php
    $dummy = "<script>document.write(sum)</script>";
    echo $dummy;
?>

Comment: Oh. You need to restrict some operation in PHP based on the sum?

Comment: I think i don´t need that. I try your code with adding multiple and is same. I want to get the value sum and convert to PHP, can i do that? The example is before that comment that works if the the value is static. For the sum of the code don´t work. You know what is happening?

Comment: You mean you want to get the sum value to PHP when the value is less than or equal to 1 and form is submitted? Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, i do that condition near where is that:  if ($sum<1) echo ('<input type="submit"  value="Submeter" class="link-style2"  />'); else {you can´t submit} Something like that.

Comment: `teste.php` is where you're taking sum value to?

Comment: No. teste.php is after submit the values. I need to do that statement in the same page you see the code on the top.

Comment: You can't do like `if($sum > 1) { echo "<code>"; } else { <you can't submit the form>  }` before even selecting the options. You're selecting the options on client side after the form is already generated from server side.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do. Let me assume what you're trying do is you generate all those array values from the database and add those values as options in `select` tag and based on selecting each value in the options, you will be adding the value to the sum on each selection and when you try to submit the form, it should not be submitted if the sum is greater than 1. Right? This is what you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: Correct. Is that i want to do.

Comment: I've written a sample code for that to see if that's what you want. You can check it out here on live. http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/q9qg-dxmj. Let me know if there is anything about the code.

Comment: Hello, i check the code but is not working for me case. You submit anyway.

Comment: It was just a sample code served as a pattern to show how it should work as per your requirements. You need to change it according to your code which involves database as well.

Comment: Hello, i already solved the problem but in another way. Thank you for kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a submit event handler to the form in question, then within that handler use code much like you've shown for your change event. If the sum is too big cancel the submit and show a message, otherwise do nothing:

```
$('#idOfYourFormHere').on('submit', function(e) {
  var sum = 0;
  $('select :selected').each(function() {
    sum += Number(this.value);
  });
  $("#sum").html(sum);

  if (sum > 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('You cannot submit unless the sum of your selections is less than or equal to 1.');
  } // else do nothing and submit will continue
});
```

Note that you don't need the change handler unless you want to show the running total, just recalculate the total when the user tries to submit.

Comment: Bro! I like your answer because of its simplicity to avoid redudancy. +1 from me for that. But according to his code, it seems he needs to display calculated `sum` each time he selects an option. So, he however requires `change` event handler.

Comment: @Perumal93 - Yeah, I just noticed that. So your answer covers it better..